Two completely different-looking adiabatic connection formula in DFT
In my  density functional theory (DFT) course, we learned that what is called the adiabatic connection formula in DFT is some formula of the form
$$ E_{\lambda = 1} - E_{\lambda = 0} = \int ^1_0 \mathrm{d}\lambda\, \left\langle \Psi_{\lambda}
\middle| \hat{H} \middle|\Psi_{\lambda} \right\rangle,$$
where $\lambda$ is some continuous parameter. This uses the Hellmann-Feynman theorem. However, in my study of a paper$^\dagger$ in the field, I came across another formula (equation (4) in the paper) which the authors say is the adiabatic connection formula$^\ddagger$:
$$E_{\text{c}} = - \int^\infty_0 \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2\pi}\int^1_0 \frac{\mathrm{d}\lambda}{\lambda} \operatorname{tr}\left[(1-\tilde{\chi}_{\lambda}V_{\lambda})^{-1}\tilde{\chi}_{\lambda}V_{\lambda} - \tilde{\chi}_0V_{\lambda} \right]. \tag{4}$$
Now searching on the internet for the term "adiabatic connection formula" doesn't return many general results, but only papers on very specific schemes; also, the formulae look nothing like the one given in the paper. Does anyone know of any general reference on this topic, or if adiabatic connection formula has a well-agreed-upon definition?
$^\dagger$: Langreth, D. C. et al. (2004). Van der Waals density functional theory with application.
$^\ddagger$: Although probably not of importance in this question, but the terms in the formula are defined as follows: $\tilde{\chi}$ is the density response to the full electric potential, $V$ is the Coulomb interaction potential, and $u$ is the imagniary frequency replacing the time variable. The meaning of the trace in the integral is in another PSE question I asked.

Reverse the order of the integrals in your second formula and you have something with the same form as your first. So what you are looking for is a way to expand the expectation value to get all of the stuff in the second formula. Based on your "probably not important" footnote, it sounds like this is an application of linear response theory and the Kubo formula

Link to abstract page?

Link to abstract page: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260071784_Van_der_Waals_Density_Functional_Theory_with_Applications

Permalink: https://doi.org/10.1002/qua.20315

I have found the answer to my own question, so here is a brief summary. The equation
$$ E_{\lambda = 1} - E_{\lambda = 0} = \int^1_0 \mathrm{d}\lambda \left\langle \Psi_\lambda \middle| \hat{H} \middle| \Psi_\lambda \right\rangle $$
is indeed the adiabatic connection formula. The other formula referenced in the paper as the adiabatic connection formula is more commonly called the adiabatic connection fluctuation-dissipation (ACFD) formula.
Cf. Hellgren, Maria; Baguet, Lucas. Random phase approximation with exchange for an accurate description of crystalline polymorphism. Phys. Rev. Research 3, 033263.
